# How to correctly block Eclipse job

Tags: java, jobs, job-scheduling

I am using org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.JOB to execute backgrounds task that also gathers data from UI controls.

I want to "block" until job is finished (the trigger for the JOB is some ui button event)

```
Job job = new Job("Job") {                                                                                        
    protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor arg0) {                  
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {               
            public void run() {                                                                             
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {                          
                    try {                                                   
                        Thread.sleep(1000);                                   
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}                                                                                              
                    System.out.println(i);                                 
                }                                                         
            }                                                           
        });                                                           
        return Status.OK_STATUS;                                      
    }                                                                                                                                  
};                                                                
job.schedule();                                                   

job.join();   //<-- Doesn't block!!!

if (job.getResult().isOK())                                     
   System.out.println("success"); //<-- Result is ok!!          
else                                                         
   System.out.println("failed");
```

Comment: your job opens a second thread which is called asynchronously (That's why the method name is asyncExec) and therefore your job returns immediately.

Comment: yeah... stupid me... it should be syncExec without the a...

Comment: but syncExec block gui...

Comment: why do you even use [a]syncExec? You are not accessing anything from GUI so it is not needed.

Comment: I am accessing , as stated in the post "task that also gathers data from UI controls.". I just removed it from post and replaces with thread.sleep